# Prove $(X \backslash Y) \cap Z = (X \cap Z) \backslash (Y \cap Z)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know I'll have to prove that the LHS is a subset of RHS and vice versa. But I'm just not too sure where to start.

Comment: Just write it out: what does it mean for an element $a$ to be in $(X \backslash Y) \cap Z$?

Comment: Given two sets $A,B$, the standard way of proving that $A = B$ is to prove that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A.$  To prove that $A\subseteq B$, you assume that element $e$ is in $A$, and then prove that element $e$ must therefore also be in $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(X \cap Z) \backslash (Y \cap Z) = \{x: x\in X \text{ and } x \in Z \text{ and } x\notin Y \cap Z\}$

$= \{x: x\in X \text{ and } x \in Z \text{ and } (x\notin Y \text{ or }  x\notin Z)\}$

$= \{x: (x\in X \text{ and } x \in Z \text{ and }  x\notin Y) \text{ or }  (x\in X \text{ and } x \in Z \text{ and } x\notin Z)\}$

$= \{x: (x\in X \text{ and } x \in Z \text{ and }  x\notin Y\} = (X \backslash Y) \cap Z$

I used these facts in this order:

(1) DeMorgans Laws: not (A and B) = not A or not B

(2) (A and B) or C = (A and C) or (B and C),

(3) (A) or (a false statement) = A

Comment: Oh!! That makes sense now thank you.

Comment: @zinvolle your welcome :3 could u accept the answer btw haha